# Rails 4 Nested Attributes and Strong Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

This is my first time messing with nested attributes. I'm having an issue where I am trying to create a 'School' that has a 'Token' and its attributes. Upon submitting the form, I'll get errors saying 'The Token attributes cannot be blank' (b/c of my model validations) even though I am submitting the form with Token values for the Token attributes.

I think things are misaligned when looking at the server logs but I'm not sure why?

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xbDhfXJotAfgg6O9rnrSuKy01cxoTi/ZpgaDuD4fkQA=", "school"=>{"name"=>"Palmer", "address"=>"123 Palmer lane", "city"=>"Baldwinsville", "state"=>"CA", "zip"=>"10001", "tokens_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"database"=>"Rhetorical studies", "start_date(1i)"=>"2013", "start_date(2i)"=>"8", "start_date(3i)"=>"29", "expiration_date(1i)"=>"2014", "expiration_date(2i)"=>"8", "expiration_date(3i)"=>"29"}}}, "commit"=>"Update"}
```

My schools model looks like this:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_many :tokens
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tokens
end
```

The schools_controller's new action looks like the following:

```
  def new
    @school = School.new
    @school.tokens.build
  end
```

My Schools form has the following fields_for:

```
<%= f.fields_for :tokens do |builder| %>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label "Database(s)" %>
    <%= builder.text_field :database %>
  <p>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label "Start Date" %><br />
    <%= builder.date_select :start_date %>
  <p>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label "Expiration Date" %><br />
    <%= builder.date_select :expiration_date %>
  <p>
<hr />
<% end -%>
```

And the 'school_params' strong params in the 'schools_controller.rb' look like this:

```
  def school_params
    params.require(:school).permit(:name, :address, :city, :state, :zip, tokens_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :school_id, :database, :start_date, :expiration_date])
  end
```

Based on the logs, it seems as though I'm doing something wrong in 'school_params'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I was working on this late last night. In doing so I had '@school.tokens.build' in both the 'new' and the 'create' actions. Removed it from 'create', and it's working fine now.